# Определение местоположения по клику Android

Tags: java, android, геолокация

Получилось сделать определение координат:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    private LocationManager locationManagerGPS;
    locationManagerGPS.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000, 0, locationListenerGPS);
  };

  public static LocationListener locationListenerGPS = new LocationListener() {
      @Override
      public void onLocationChanged(Location locationGPS) {
        System.out.println(Double.toString(locationGPS.getLongitude()));
        System.out.println(Double.toString(locationGPS.getLatitude()));
      }
      @Override
      public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) { }
      @Override
      public void onProviderEnabled(String s) { }
      @Override
      public void onProviderDisabled(String s) { }
  };
}
```

Но координаты определяются только когда изменяется местоположение.
Есть ли возможность сделать определение текущего местоположения по клику кнопки?

Т.е., например, было какое то движение, определялись координаты, прибыли на место, надо узнать местоположение остановки, нажали на кнопку "финиш" и определяется текущая координата.

Comment: Вообще у вас данные обновляются не только, когда изменится местоположение, но и каждые 5 сек. Лучше использовать (LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0,0, locationListenerGPS) дабы сразу узнать координаты.

Answer (score 1):

Просто в onLocationChanged сохраняй последние полученные координаты, а при нажатии на кнопку используй их.

Для повышения частоты определения координат и точности задай параметры LOCATION_REFRESH_TIME и LOCATION_REFRESH_DISTANCE.

```
locationManagerGPS.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
LOCATION_REFRESH_TIME, LOCATION_REFRESH_DISTANCE, locationListenerGPS);
```

Или же можешь использовать последние координаты, которые запомнила система(но это не лучший вариант)

```
 if (locationManager != null) {
    location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    if (location != null) {
       latitude = location.getLatitude();
       longitude = location.getLongitude();
       }
 }
```

Comment: использовать последние координаты совсем не годится
я пытался ставить минимальное время обновления 0, но это работает только при включенном GPS при создании активити, но это же ест зарядку, а при включении по клику, координаты не определяются

Comment: Вам принципиально использование только GPS?

Comment: @Miwqa Вам нужно один раз получать данные или сколько-то?

Comment: @LexHobbit, в данный момент да

Comment: @iFr0z, один раз, я сделал сервис, который запускается раз в какое то время и определяет координаты, теперь мне надо как бы завершение движения по клику

Comment: @Miwqa locationManagerGPS.removeUpdates(this); для того, чтобы остановить получение координат